# Automatically inflating parent and children ListFragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Is there a way to automatically create a ListFragment containing just TextViews and when an item in the list is clicked, create another ListFragment with TextViews and so on, up until an item with no children at which point clicking on it launches some other action?

Basically I just need to drill down through categories and subcategories and sub-subcategories and so on until I reach a value that doesn't have it's own list and instead corresponds to another action entirely.

I feel like there might be an easy way to do this through XML, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: That's just a very bad user experience... consider some other alternatives.

Comment: What he said. You are describing a tree control which was left out of Android on purpose. Is it possible yes, but unless you are developing a tablet only app it should be avoided.

Comment: What are some alternatives you would suggest? This is only for a very small part of the app for browsing categories and subcategories so I don't really know how else to approach it.